# I am having problem in creating react app

Tags: reactjs, installation

It is freezing at a point. It says "found 1 low severity vulnerability   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details". I have installed node v-12.18.3 and npm 6.14.6. Antivirus is also turned off. Help me out please.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to run npm audit fix? The vulnerability is usually a package something in your project is dependent on. I would not be to worried about a low severity if it a local project and npm audit fix doesn't fix it.
If you run npm audit you can se what package it is and try to install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

1. `npm install react react-dom --save`
2. `npx create-react-app your-app`
3. `cd your-app`
4. `npm start`